# Save duplicates with most recent date and remove others from oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently I have a situation where I want to delete duplicates from a table in oracle. The problem is I want to save the most recent row (according to date field) and delete other duplicates. For example here is a small snapshot of my table:

```
TASK:(num, code, downtime)
--------------------------
   123  2432  7/13/2014 10:27
   123  2784  7/13/2014 11:57
   154  2232  8/9/2014  12:11
   154  2523  8/12/2014 01:27
```

I want the remaining table would be:

```
   123  2784  7/13/2014  11:57
   154  2523  8/12/2014  01:27
```

Would you please tell me what oracle query meets my requirements?

Comment: At first take a look at [this](http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
delete task 
 where (num, downtime) not in (
  select num, max(downtime) 
    from task
   group by num
)
```

Comment: Really simple and fantastic query

Comment: You have to memorize it, the task to remove duplicates occurs very often